# ToString on Object generate error

Tags: java, object, tostring

I'm trying to display my Object content.
I use ORM. I have Delivery who contains a list of User. In delivery.toString() I make this:

```
    `    
@Override
public String toString() {
    String usersReadables = "";

    try {
        CloseableIterator<User> userIterator = this.getUsers().closeableIterator();

        try {
            // For each user.
            while (userIterator.hasNext()) {
                usersReadables += usersReadables.length() > 0 ? ", " : "";
                User user = userIterator.next();
                usersReadables += user.getName();
            }
        } finally {
            // Always close the iterator, else the connection from the database
            // isn't destroyed.
            try {
                userIterator.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                Log.e(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        usersReadables = null;
    }

    return "Delivery [deliveryId=" + deliveryId + ", round=" + round + ", typeDelivery=" + typeDelivery + ", priority=" + priority + ", deliveryOver=" + deliveryOver + ", receiverAvailable=" + receiverAvailable + ", signature=" + signature + ", dateOver=" + dateOver + ", latitude=" + latitude + ", longitude=" + longitude + ", users=" + usersReadables + ", sender=" + sender + ", receiver=" + receiver + "]";
}`
```

But if I try to do usersReadables += user.toString();
The program generate an Exception. I don't understand why.
I had override User.toString too for display correctly my users but...

Do you have any idea ?
Thank you.

Comment: which exception is being raised?

Comment: @DanielPereira No error, it's seems to be an infinite while...
Always call the same line with the deboguer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems as if the reason you're getting an error is because the userReadables is initially set to a null string. in the catch, you have

```
catch(Exception e) {
   userReadables = null;
}
```

and since the userReadables is already null, it's calling the Exception before it does anything else. Make it something related to the program. Change it to

```
String userReadables = " ";
```

that way it will at least be registered as a space, and not null.

Hope this helps!

Comment: PS what is the stray ` mark at the top and the bottom of the code?

Comment: Did you miss `String usersReadables = "";` at the start?

Comment: @all This is no error log. In the catch, the Exception e.getMessage() return null. No way for me to understand this error.
I'm using the debugger, but it seems my User.toString() call Delivery.toString() and I'm in an infinite while...

Comment: There is a way to **convert an object to string automatically** who contains all parameters of the object without specified for each param ? Using reflexion, probably.